# Does a second (inner) loop open a subprocess?

Tags: linux, shell

I have come to an interesting topic, while I was experimenting
recursive loops in a shell script.

First I came across interesting functionality of

```
for x in a b c d; do
 for x in e f d h; do
  a=test
 done
 echo $x
done
```

Always outputting letter h as variable $x. Which makes sense, as inner loop uses x as variable name too, and h would be the last one picked in such loop.

My concern is, does inner loops open a subprocess or how is the functionality guaranteed?

```
for x in a b c d; do
 for x in e f d h; do
  pstree $$
 done
 pstree $$
done
```

.. suggest in the output that no sub-processes are opened on nested loops.

I am probably a little bit stuck in a loop, but is there a good documentation how a shell operates loops? I would like to know how does shell interpret the loops so it's kept within one layer of instructions.

Comment: Why would a subprocess be needed for your observed behavior? It's the other way around; you'd only see x if there *wasn't* a subprocess

Comment: Other than execline variants, I've never seen or heard of a language runtime that *would* use a subprocess here, so I'm unclear on why it's something you're worried about.

Comment: It would be better to use a different looping vatiable in the internal loop. Now it is innocent (x becomes a, e, f, d, h, b, e, f, d, h, c, e, f, d, h, d, e, f, d, h) but can cause an infinite loop in other situations. When will `i` get 10 in `for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do for ((i=0;i<5;i++));..`

Comment: The guarantee comes from the definition of a `for` loop: the name is assigned a new value at each iteration. The fact that you are using the same name in both loops doesn't change that.

Comment: There is no recursion in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your example in this way:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -x

for x in a b; do
  : x=$x
  for x in c d; do
    : x=$x
    a=test
  done
  echo $x
done
```

This outputs:

```
+ for x in a b
+ : x=a
+ for x in c d
+ : x=c
+ a=test
+ for x in c d
+ : x=d
+ a=test
+ echo d
d
+ for x in a b
+ : x=b
+ for x in c d
+ : x=c
+ a=test
+ for x in c d
+ : x=d
+ a=test
+ echo d
d
```

Now you can see, the inner loop modifies `x` after the outer loop. When you print `x` it has always the last value of the inner loop.